# How to present ViewController in full screen with behavior of popover? Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I need to present VC in full screen, but with ability to swipe it down as it was popover, similar to how it works in Apple Music in song details.

I've tried every option in vc.modalPresentationStyle, but it's either in full screen without ability to swipe down to close or with this ability, but not in full screen

```
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
```

[image: Apple Music reference]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I just presented it in full screen and wrote function, which allows pan to close vc, with decreasing alpha

```
func panToCloseGesture() {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func handlePanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let percentThreshold:CGFloat = 0.3
        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
        
        let newY = self.ensureRange(value: view.frame.minY + translation.y, minimum: 0, maximum: view.frame.maxY)
        let progress = self.progressAlongAxis(newY, view.bounds.height)
        
        view.frame.origin.y = newY
        if newY > 0 {
            self.rootView.alpha = 1 - (newY / 400)
        }
        
         if sender.state == .ended {
            let velocity = sender.velocity(in: view)
            if velocity.y >= 1000 || progress > percentThreshold {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    self.rootView.alpha = 1
                    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
                })
            }
        }
        sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `modalPresentationStyle`:

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
```

2. Set `preferredContentSize`:

```
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: kScreenWidth, height: kScreenHeight)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, .preferredContentSize didn't help. It's just doesn't change anything whatever value I put in height

Comment: Yes, `preferredContentSize` is used for iPad screen :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```